# Select monthly counts of data across two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, lastfm_scrobbles and lastfm_annotations. Example data:

```
mysql> select * from lastfm_scrobbles limit 5;
+---------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| user_id | item_id | artist_id | scrobble_time       |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
|    1469 |   45651 |         1 | 2010-06-30 13:57:42 |
|    1469 |   45651 |         1 | 2011-03-28 15:43:37 |
|    6872 |   45653 |         1 | 2013-08-03 15:07:44 |
|    7044 |    1370 |         1 | 2007-03-26 17:07:26 |
|    7044 |    1370 |         1 | 2007-08-24 18:41:35 |
+---------+---------+-----------+---------------------+

mysql> select * from lastfm_annotations limit 5;
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+------------+
| user_id | item_id | artist_id | tag_id | tag_month  |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+------------+
|     121 | 1330412 |   1330412 |    475 | 2006-12-01 |
|     121 | 1330412 |   1330412 |    517 | 2006-12-01 |
|     121 | 1330412 |   1330412 |   7280 | 2006-12-01 |
|     121 | 1330412 |   1330412 |  21384 | 2006-12-01 |
|     121 | 1330412 |   1330412 |  27872 | 2006-12-01 |
+---------+---------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

Furthermore, I have a user information table (lastfm_users). The details of this aren't important, but what is relevant is that the query:

```
select user_id from lastfm_users where scrobbles_recorded==1;
```

Returns the users I care about for the purposes of this question.

Ok, with that preamble out of the way: I need a query that will get me, for those users, the total number of entries they have in both the scrobbles and annotations tables for each month. In other words, the result should look something like:

```
user_id y       m       scrobble_count  anno_count
123     2006    3       100             50
456     2008    11      321             10
... and so on
```

Make sense? I believe the query I want is a combination of the following:

```
select year(tag_month) as y, month(tag_month) as m, count(*) as anno_count 
    from lastfm_annotations where user_id in (select user_id from 
        lastfm_users where scrobbles_recorded=1) 
    group by user_id, year(tag_month), month(tag_month);


select year(scrobble_time) as y, month(scrobble_time) as m, count(*) as scrobble_count 
    from lastfm_scrobbles where user_id in (select user_id from 
        lastfm_users where scrobbles_recorded=1) 
    group by user_id, year(scrobble_time), month(scrobble_time);
```

But I'm not certain of the correct way to generate the join query to get the result I want. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```sql
select user_id, y, m, 
       coalesce(sum(case when source = 1 then total end), 0) anno_count,
       coalesce(sum(case when source = 2 then total end), 0) scrobble_count
  from
(
  select 1 source, a.user_id, year(tag_month) y, month(tag_month) m, count(*) total 
    from lastfm_annotations a join lastfm_users u
      on a.user_id = u.user_id
   where u.scrobbles_recorded = 1
   group by user_id, year(tag_month), month(tag_month)
   union all
  select 2 source, s.user_id, year(scrobble_time), month(scrobble_time), count(*) 
    from lastfm_scrobbles s join lastfm_users u
      on s.user_id = u.user_id
   where u.scrobbles_recorded = 1
   group by user_id, year(scrobble_time), month(scrobble_time)
) q
group by user_id, y, m
```

or just

```sql
select user_id, y, m, 
       sum(case when source = 1 then 1 else 0 end) anno_count,
       sum(case when source = 2 then 1 else 0 end) scrobble_count
  from
(
  select 1 source, a.user_id, year(tag_month) y, month(tag_month) m 
    from lastfm_annotations a join lastfm_users u
      on a.user_id = u.user_id
   where u.scrobbles_recorded = 1
   union all
  select 2 source, s.user_id, year(scrobble_time), month(scrobble_time)
    from lastfm_scrobbles s join lastfm_users u
      on s.user_id = u.user_id
   where u.scrobbles_recorded = 1
) q
 group by user_id, y, m;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6845f/9)** demo

Comment: Thanks! Running these now to verify they work on my data and will accept once that's done. In the meantime, could you elaborate a bit on the two methods? Which one is preferred and why?

Comment: 4 hours in and the query (second version) is still running...I'm wondering if just doing this iteratively might be faster at this point.

Comment: The most likely cause of this is underindexing. Run `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: Explain result is too long for comment. Here is a screengrab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ca8zcgif3ypalt5/Screenshot%202014-02-16%2015.36.05.png